# How do I get started creating Mac applications?

Tags: ios, macos

I am currently an iPhone application developer. As an iPhone developer, I figured I could also create and sell Mac applications now that there is a Mac Application Store.

I have learned from Apple that - similar to what is required for the iPhone - I need to join their Mac Developer program for $99 in order to submit applications to the Mac Application Store.

My question is multi-part:

- How similar is developing for the Mac to developing for the iPhone?
- What resources are available for learning how to create Mac Applications?

Comment: Thanks jordan for formatting to get a better answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In basic terms Mac programming can be though of as a "superset" of iPhone programming. Note that this is not strictly true, but provides a rough idea of things.
There are things such as garbage collection, foundation classes, Cocoa Bindings, Carbon, etc. that have no presence on IOS.

So to answer your first question, noit's not the same but it is similar.

There are some great answers to a similar question here: [From iPhone to Mac programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062438/from-iphone-to-mac-programming)
In general the resources you will want to start with are Apple's own, provided on the Mac Dec Center website. http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/index.action

Comment: Couldn't have answered it better myself! While I was busy editing the question to clean it up, you gave it a great answer.

Comment: As an additional note, since this is the chosen answer, you do not need to pay for the Mac developer program _until_ you want to publish your app.  There are benefits to it, but for the most part you can probably ignore it until later.  That way, if you decide it's not worth it to develop for Mac OS, you're not out $100.

Comment: Nil is correct, but the one benefit of the program is getting access to pre-release versions of the upcoming operating system. This can be quite valuable and I would consider getting before it is time to publish, so you can conduct compatibility testing. You can rest assured that Apple will be doing so.

Answer (score 5):

You're in luck!  They've got many of the same foundations (Cocoa, Foundation, Obj-C)!  I made my biggest initial strides in mac programming reading Cocoa Programming for Mac OS by Aaron Hillegass.
[http://www.amazon.com/Cocoa-Programming-Mac-OS-3rd/dp/0321503619/ref=trdrt_list_asin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619)

Comment: Don't know why this was voted down. Seemed kind of petty to me. I voted it up, so this guy's rep is not damaged.

Comment: @Jordan, someone probably saw the Amazon link and assumed spam. Actually, there are no downvotes against this post right now.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus - Looks like the down vote was removed. There was one, which is no longer there.