# Good Resources to learn Mac OS X Development for an iPhone Developer

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocoa, macos

I'm an experienced iOS developer, and know UIKit and most of the Foundation classes like the back of my hand. I've been toying around with a Mac App, but some of the basic app structure I'm not sure about. For example - in the iOS world there is only one "window" and a UIViewController for each screenful of information (for the most part). On OS X though, I see NSViewController which sounds like it may be useful, but then I also see things like NSWindowController which looks like it's tied in to the NSDocument stuff (which I'm not creating a document-based app) and some other things which make me second-guess myself.

Anyway, I'm not sure how to organize all my views, nibs, etc and I'm hoping maybe there are some good resources out there that can explain all the paradigms for OS X development to someone who is used to iOS development. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: possible duplicate of [From iPhone to Mac programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062438/from-iphone-to-mac-programming)

Comment: As well as: [Tips for an iOS developer to learn Mac programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984159/tips-for-an-ios-developer-to-learn-mac-programming) | [iPhone to Mac development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161663/iphone-to-mac-development) | [How do I get started creating Mac applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100369/how-do-i-get-started-creating-mac-applications) [Difference between iPhone development and Mac OS X development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553305/) [Jumping from iOS to OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915656)

Comment: I've seen most of those, but many of them weren't very helpful. That's why I also put in some specific questions about the controllers and such and their counterparts.

Answer (score 1):

I thinki Apple has a pretty good document describing the architecture of it's os X application. Look at the section `Applications Are Built Using Many Different Pieces` and `The Application Style Determines the Core Architecture` of the [Mac OS X Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide.pdf)